# Java constructor

Tags: java

How do I define a single constructor `public packet(String[] biscuit)` which makes my field from `private String[] biscuitList` to `private String[] biscuit`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "makes my field from ... to ...".  Please elucidate.

Comment: What do you want to do? Example code will help too.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, let me word it better, what im trying to do is to set a single constructor that will change the ending of 1 of my fields e.g. from "biscuitList" to "biscuit"

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign it to the field.

```
public class Packet {
    private String[] biscuitList;
    public Packet(String[] biscuit) {
        this.biscuitList = biscuit;
    }
}
```

The `this` refers to the **current** `Packet` instance (which you just created using `new Packet`). The `this.biscuitList` refers to the `biscuitList` field of the current `Packet` instance. The `= biscuit` assigns the given `biscuit` to the left hand (which in this case is the `biscuitList` field.

That said, a `String[]` variable shouldn't really be called with a name ending in `List`. This may cause ambiguity with a `List<String>`. You can just call it `biscuit`, or maybe better, `biscuits`.

```
public class Packet {
    private String[] biscuits;
    public Packet(String[] biscuits) {
        this.biscuits= biscuits;
    }
}
```

Also, classnames and constructor names ought to start with uppercase. I.e. `Packet` and not `packet`.

To learn more about Java, check the [Trials Covering the Basics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/).

Comment: It should be said, that the this-keyword, in the first case, has no effect - it could just as well be left out. 
Usually, its used when there is a name-clash, and we need to distinguish between the instance-variable, and the local variable. (see the second case, which exactly illustrates this point).

Comment: @noob11: It should also be said, sentences start with an uppercase and ends with a dot. No, "i am a noob" is not a valid excuse at all. This makes no sense. You also don't need to state that explicitly in every topic. Just show that you're putting effort in asking the question the smart way. That's really all. Also see http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
this.biscuitList = biscuit;
```

Comment: so the above code do the following?

change the ending of 1 of my fields e.g. from          

private String[] biscuitList;

to

private String[] biscuit;

Comment: I think you are confused about private class fields and constructor parameters. The above assumes biscutList is your private field and biscuit is your parameter. So we are assigning biscuitList with the value of biscuit, so that you can refer to biscuitList in your methods.